# No record save in room database

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-viewmodel

> After inserting data into RoomDB when I fetch it using `mindValleyDao.getCategories().value` It returns null

**DatabaseClass**

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(CategoryBO::class), version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class MindValleyDatabase : RoomDatabase(){

    abstract fun mindValleyDao(): MindValleyDao

    companion object {
        // Singleton prevents multiple instances of database opening at the
        // same time.
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: MindValleyDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context): MindValleyDatabase {
            val tempInstance = INSTANCE
            if (tempInstance != null) {
                return tempInstance
            }
            synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                        context.applicationContext,
                        MindValleyDatabase::class.java,
                        "mindvalley_database"
                ).allowMainThreadQueries()
                        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration().build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                return instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**CategoryBO.kt**

```
@Entity(tableName = "CategoryEntity")
data class CategoryBO( @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id:Int, val name:String)
```

**Doa**

```
@Dao
interface MindValleyDao {

    @Query("SELECT * from CategoryEntity ORDER BY id ASC")
    fun getCategories(): LiveData<List<CategoryBO>>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(categoryBO: CategoryBO)
    //suspend fun insert(categoryBO: CategoryBO)

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(categoryBOList: List<CategoryBO>)
}
```

I am testing it by inserting Category and fetching list of categories like

```
class MindValleyViewModelNew @Inject constructor() : BaseViewModel() {

    var categoryList: MutableLiveData<List<CategoryBO>> = MutableLiveData()
    private lateinit var mindValleyDao:MindValleyDao

    fun loadDatabase(mContext:Context){
        mindValleyDao = MindValleyDatabase.getDatabase(mContext).mindValleyDao()
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            mindValleyDao.insert(CategoryBO(0,"first item"))
            val cats = mindValleyDao.getCategories().value
            categoryList.postValue(cats)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mindValleyDao.getCategories()` has return type is LiveData, that's why it query value async, you shouldn't call `.value`

LiveData type in Room should only use for observe,

If you want to get value, modify your code to `fun getCategories(): List<CategoryBO>` instead